# Team Build Agent creating workspace using the Location option as Local

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there some way to define Team build agent to create a workspace with option Location as Local?

On configuration Team Collection -> Source Control Settings -> Workspace Settings the default workspace type is setted as Local, but the Team Build seems to ignore it when creating the workspace.

I looked into the source code of the CreateWorkspace Activity used on DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml template, and it seems I have no option to do so.

```
public static Workspace CreateWorkspace(VersionControlServer versionControl, string name, IEnumerable folders, string comment, IEnumerable wsSecurity) {
    ...
        if (array.Length == 0)
        {
            CreateWorkspaceParameters createWorkspaceParameters = new CreateWorkspaceParameters(name)
            {
                Comment = comment,
                Folders = (folders == null) ? new WorkingFolder[0] : folders.ToArray(),
                Location = new WorkspaceLocation?(WorkspaceLocation.Server)
            };
            workspace = versionControl.CreateWorkspace(createWorkspaceParameters);
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you care if it creates local or server workspace?

Comment: I'm using Typescript and during the build time on build server, it's try overwrite some .js files. As workspace location is setted as Server, the build fails.

Comment: It's using Server, as it's much faster. Why are both the typescript files and the javascript files checked into source control?